# sum number of cells based on current date in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a spreadsheet like this:

```
date | 7/1 | 7/2 | 7/3 | 7/4
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
 val |  3  |  5  |  1  |  3  
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
```

I want to sum the val row, but only up to the current date. So if today were 7/3, the sum would be 3+5+1=9. If today were 7/4, it would be 12.

I figured this out to get the number of columns:

```
=YEARFRAC(B1,TODAY())*360  // B1 is the first date -- 7/1
```

but I can't figure out how to tell excel to do the sum:

```
=SUM(B2:<B+num cols above>2)
```

Presumably its something to do with references, and lookup, but I'm not really familiar with how those work....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A1:E1,"<="&TODAY(),A2:E2)
```

Assuming your dates are in a1:e1 and your values are in a2:e2.

Answer (score 0):

The [OFFSET function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991) should do the job. There's a similar question [here](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/Conditional-sum-elements-range.htm). Without knowing the exact layout of your table, I guess your formula would look something like:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,DAY(TODAY())))
```

Where DAY(TODAY()) returns the day in the month. This number is then used as the width of the range to SUM over in OFFSET.

I hope that was relatively clear. Good luck.

Comment: this also works:
=SUM(OFFSET(C2,0,0,1,YEARFRAC(C1,TODAY())*360+1))

(can't count on the days corresponding to the number of offsets)

but it's more complex...

Answer (score 0):

Put this VBA in a module

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetTotal(StartCell As Range) As Integer 
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    i = StartCell.Row
    j = StartCell.Column

    If Cells(i, j) > Date Then
        GetTotal = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    While Cells(i, j) <> DateAdd("d", 1, Date) 'values up to an including today'
        GetTotal = GetTotal + Cells(i + 1, j)
        j = j + 1
    Wend

End Function
```

and then use it in a worksheet cell by inserting

```
=GetTotal([starting date cell])
```

where `[starting date cell]` is the cell with the date from which you want the sum. The worksheet cell's value will be the sum

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to get the sum of the values between the dates.

1. Using sumifs

   =SUMIFS(B2:B15,A2:A15,">="&F3,A2:A15,"<="&F4)
2. Using sumproduct

   =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A15>=F3)*(A2:A15<=F4),B2:B15)
3. Using offset

   =SUM(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(F3,A2:A15,0),0,MATCH(F4,A2:A15,0)-MATCH(F3,A2:A15,0)+1,1))

If Date range is in A column and val range is in B column.

[image]

[image]